# Sumar con condiciones SQL

Tags: sql

Estoy aprendiendo SQL y tengo una base de datos con dos columnas vacias, `Suma`, `Producto` y quiero sumar los attributos de los nombres selecionados (les puse un `*` para que sepan cuales seleccione) y quiero ponerle condicion a mi suma de acuerdo a su tamaño y el resultado de la condicion lo quiero poner en la columna producto pero no se como hacer esto.

```
INSERT INTO Atleticos.Producto (Suma) VALUES (SUMA)

SELECT SUM(Attributos) Suma FROM Atleticos WHERE name = '????*'

IF Suma < 0.6
Producto = Suma*4 
ELSEIF Suma >= 0.6 and Suma<= 5
Producto = Suma * 3 + 5 
ELSE
Producto = Suma * 2;
ENDIF
```

> Suma < 0.6, Multiplicarla por 4 y almacenarlo en Producto
>
> 0.6 ≤ Suma ≤ 5, Multiplicarla por 3 + 5 y almacenarlo en Producto
>
> Suma > 5, Multiplicarla por 2 y almacenarlo en Producto

Esta es la tabla, suma y producto es lo que quiero llenar

```
Nombres Attributos  Altura  Suma    Producto
Pedro*    0.5         5.1    0.5    2
Anna      0.6         4.3       
Carla*    0.3         6.4    0.8    7.4
Johan*    0.4         3.4    1.2    8.6
Bryan     10           6        
Cecilia*   5          5.7    6.2    12.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu query debe ir de la siguiente manera:

```
UPDATE Atleticos
SET Producto = CASE
    when Suma < 0.6 THEN Suma*4
    when Suma >= 0.6 AND Suma<= 5 THEN Suma * 3 + 5
    ELSE Suma * 2
END
WHERE name = '????*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Considera hacerlo mediante un trigger (la sintaxis puede cambiar dependiendo de tu manejador de base de datos) si en realidad quieres que el dato esté en la tabla, pero eso ocupará espacio innecesariamente. Lo mejor en esos casos es crear una vista para que el dato se calcule al momento de ejecutar la consulta. Ejemplo:

```
CREATE VIEW view_atleticos as SELECT *, CASE
when Suma < 0.6 THEN Suma*4
when Suma >= 0.6 AND Suma<= 5 THEN Suma * 3 + 5
ELSE Suma * 2
END Suma FROM Atleticos
```

Y usar tu vista en tus selects.